# How do I include external javascript file using thymeleaf?

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm using Spring Boot / MVC and learning Thymeleaf.

Let's say i have my scripts on another server.

https://staticserver.com/main.js

I've added the '//staticserver.com' portion to my model as `jsLocation`.

I want to do something on the lines of:

`<script src="${jsLocation}/main.js"></script>`

which would render

`<script src="//staticserver.com/main.js"></script>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<script th:src="|${jsLocation}/main.js|"></script>
```

Comment: I used this solution to drop my google api key into the places javascript library request

`<script th:src="|https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${googleApiKey}&libraries=places|"></script>`

Comment: It is very weird and ODD syntax. I don't understand why not defined like `th:src="/my/script/path/${fname}"`

Answer (score 3):

You can include external js file like below :

```
<script th:src="source to your external JS"></script>
```

You can refer below thread for more details as your query also relates to model.

[Thymeleaf external javascript file shares the module attributes with html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49431869/thymeleaf-external-javascript-file-shares-the-module-attributes-with-html-file)

Answer (score 1):

if your js file in `/resources/static/js/`

```
<script th:src="@{/resources/static/js/fileName.js}"> </script>
```