# Accesing external Javascript (Chart.js) with Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, chart.js, thymeleaf

i am trying some time now, to get the Chart.js in external file working with Thymeleaf. I was checking in countless external forums but couldnt find an answer. The closes to what i could find is the following
[Thymeleaf external javascript file shares the module attributes with html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49431869/thymeleaf-external-javascript-file-shares-the-module-attributes-with-html-file)

but i still didn't manage to do it.

Here is my Controller

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class ChartController {

    @RequestMapping("/ExternalChart")

    public String hello(Model model) {

        String label[] = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","adasda","adasda2"};

        int point[] = {5,3,7,1,8,3,4,50};

        model.addAttribute("label",label);
        model.addAttribute("point",point);

        return "ExternalChart";
    }

}
```

html file is located in src/main/resources/templates/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href="../static/css/Layout.css" th:href="@{/css/test.css}"
    rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../static/js/drawChart.js" th:href="@{/js/drawChart.js}"
    rel="javascript" />
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Donkey</h2>
    <p>punch</p>
    <canvas id="ChartDemo"></canvas>
    <script
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript"
        th:src="@{/js/drawChart.js}">
        /*<![CDATA[*/
        var xAxisData = /*[[ ${label} ]]*/[];
        var yAxisData = /*[[ ${point} ]]*/[];
        drawchart(xAxisData, yAxisData);
        /*]]>*/
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My javascript. it is located in src/main/resources/static/js

```
function drawchart(xAxisData, yAxisData) {

    var ctx = document.getElementById("ChartDemo").getContext('2d');
    var ChartDemo = new Chart(ctx, {
        type : 'line',
        data : {

            labels : xAxisData,
            datasets : [ {
                label : "Chart-1",
                borderColor : 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
                lineTension : 0,
                fill : false,
                data : yAxisData,
            }, ]
        },
        options : {
            responsive : true,
        }
    });
}
```

What i have noticed is that the attributes xAxisData and yAxisData get the values, but it seams that the drawChart(xAxisData,yAxisData) doesn't not get executed in browser.

I assume that i am making some silly mistake, and prospects of me finding it alone is close to zero. Thanks to anybody even trying to help me out 
BR HK

p.s. i am really new with JS

Comment: Without some kind of error message to go off, there isn't enough (and also too much) information here. See this section on [creating a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1):

I kind of have an answer. In this youtube video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AEy7Hlz58bw? it is explained how to "externalize" JavaScript files. However, it is not really intuitive.

Javascript had to be written without function() part (which is something that i dont really understand)

```
//function done(xAxisData, yAxisData) {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("ChartDemo").getContext('2d');
    var ChartDemo = new Chart(ctx, {
        type : 'line',
        data : {

            labels : xAxisData,
            datasets : [ {
                label : "Chart-1",
                borderColor : 'rgb(10, 0, 0)',
                lineTension : 0,
                fill : false,
                data : yAxisData,
            }, ]
        },
        options : {
            responsive : true,
        }
    });
//}
```

and respective HTML needs to look like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href="../static/css/Layout.css" th:href="@{/css/test.css}"
    rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../static/js/drawChart.js" th:href="@{/js/drawChart.js}"
    rel="javascript" />

</head>
<body>
    <h2>Donkey</h2>
    <p>punch</p>
    <canvas id="ChartDemo"></canvas>
    <script
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
        /*<![CDATA[*/
        var xAxisData = /*[[ ${label} ]]*/[];
        var yAxisData = /*[[ ${point} ]]*/[];
        /*]]>*/
    </script>
    <script src="/js/drawChart.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

basically part where attributes xAxisData and yAxisData are initialized, could not contain the external script file. 
If i manage to find more suitable solution, i will be glad to post it as an update to this answer as i have noticed that a lot of people get stuck in similar problems

BR DK